# Determine the base of $\ker\phi$ and fibre of phi of a polynom function

Tags: linear-algebra

Good evening,

given is a base $B$ defined as 
$$B:=(x\mapsto1,x\mapsto x,x\mapsto x^2,x\mapsto x^3 ,x\mapsto x^4)$$ a set $V$ defined as $$V:= \{ f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}\ |\ \exists\ {a_0},...{a_4} \in \mathbb{R}\ : f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{4}{a_ix^i} \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ a function $\phi$ defined as $$\phi(f)(x)=f''(x)+x \cdot f'(x) - f(x+1)$$  (where $f'(x)$ is the first derivative and $f''(x)$ the second derivative)

and an element $g, g \in V$ $$g(x)=3x^4+2x^3-x+1$$

The task is to find a base of the kernel of phi and to determine $\phi^{-1}(\{g\})$.

To determine a base of the $\ker\phi$ I need to find all functions that map to $0$. But before that I calculated the mapping rule (? not sure on the english word).
$$\phi(\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\e\end{pmatrix}) = \phi(\lambda_1\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+\lambda_2\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+\lambda_3\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+\lambda_4\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+\lambda_5\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix})$$
The next step was to determine the coefficients $\lambda_1, ... ,\lambda_5$ which directly result of this matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0&| & a \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0&| & b\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0&| & c \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0&|& d \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1&|& e \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\Rightarrow \lambda_1 = a, \lambda_2 = b, \lambda_3 = c, \lambda_4 = d, \lambda_5 = e$$
Knowing this we can continue finding the mapping rule:

$$\overset{\phi\ linear}= a\cdot\phi(\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix})+b\cdot\phi(\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix})+c\cdot\phi(\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix})+d\cdot\phi(\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix})+e\cdot\phi(\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix})$$

$$=a\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+b\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+c\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+d\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-1\\3\\-3\\2\\0\end{pmatrix}+e\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-1\\-4\\6\\-4\\3\end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix}-a-b+c-d-e\\-2c+3d-4e\\c-3d+6e\\2d-4e\\3e\end{pmatrix}$$

So far so good, now using the definition: $\ker\phi:=\{v \in V:\phi(v)=0\}.$

$$\begin{pmatrix}-a-b+c-d-e\\-2c+3d-4e\\c-3d+6e\\2d-4e\\3e\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\Rightarrow e=0,d=0,c=0,-a=b$$

Now I've got a problem choosing a base due to $-a=b$. As far as I can tell a base of $\ker\phi$ would have 2 elements in this case which aren't linear independent. I thought of: $$\{a\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+b\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} | a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

For the other question I need to know the $\ker\phi$ since for $\forall v \in V, g\in \phi(g): $$\phi^{-1}({g})= v + \ker\phi$$

Anyway I calculated $v$ by solving this equation:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-a-b+c-d-e\\-2c+3d-4e\\c-3d+6e\\2d-4e\\3e\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\Rightarrow v =x^4+3x^3+3x^2-2$$

If you need further information simply ask in this thread. I hope I described the problem detailed enough.

Comment: First, this is way too long a question; second, the vector space is most probably the vector space of *real* polynomials of degree up to four, and **not** functions; third, what you call "the mapping rule" seems to be the result of considering coordinate vectors instead of the "abstract" ones, the polynomials. What's this for I'm not sure but perhaps you were trying to get a matrix representation of that linearoperator $\,\phi\,$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imo it'd be easier (or at least slightly less messier) as follows:

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^4a_kx^k\implies $$

$$f(x)\in\ker\phi\iff f''(x)+xf'(x)=f(x+1)\iff$$

$$2a_2+(6a_3+a_1)x+(12a_4+2a_2)x^2+3a_3x^3+4a_4x^4=$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^4a_k+\left(\sum_{k=1}^4ka_k\right)x+\left(a_2+3a_3+6a_4\right)x^2+\left(a_3+4a_4\right)x^3+a_4x^4$$

Comparing corresponding powers of $\;x\;$ we get:

$$4a_4=a_4\iff a_4=0\\3a_3=a_3\iff a_3=0\\2a_2=a_2\iff a_2=0\\a_1=a_1\\a_0=-a_1$$

We thus get that

$$f(x)\in\ker\phi\iff f(x)=a-ax\;,\;\;a\in\Bbb R\implies \dim\ker\phi=1\;,\;\;\ker\phi=\text{Span}\{1-x\}$$

Comment: Hello Antonio, thanks for your answer. Shouldn't the dim$\ker\phi$ be 2? Considering the Rank-nullity Theorem dim V = 5 and dim Im = 3 or am I mistaken? For polynoms with a degree $\leq$ n the dimension of the vector space is described as $n+1$.

Comment: Unless I made a mistake, the kernel of $\;\phi\;$ is spanned by one single vector, as shown in the answer, and thus its dimension is one and from here it'd follow that $\,\dim\text{Im}\phi=4\;$

Comment: But the vector is a combination of the first and second entry of the base B, thus we would have 2 linear independent vectors, no?

Comment: No, the general vector belonging to $\,\ker\phi\,$ I got is a linear combination of $\,1-x\,$ , **not** of $\,1\,$ **and** $\,x\,$ separatedly...!

Comment: Ok I understood it now, thanks for your patience!